# Kannada language: some characters not rendering properly(Displaying different character) in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

Does iOS support Kannada language? I have browse around a couple of hours to find some tips but couldn't get through.
Here is the most annoying character that is displayed differently in iOS 
ರ್. Due to some reason, its displaying properly here but in iOS app, its displaying like ɛ.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. For example, if I browse this page in MobileSafari or in the Stack Exchange app, it renders ರ್ correctly (iOS 10). Is the text encoded in utf-8? Is it actually "ɛ" or are you just selecting that letter to demonstrate what it looks like? (That's a very odd substitution if iOS were doing it; that's LATIN SMALL LETTER OPEN E, not even part of the Kannada block.) Can you provide some code that demonstrates this issue? Note that I don't believe iOS supports Kannada as a language choice, but it should support rendering Kannada Unicode.

Comment: Yes, its looking like "ɛ". Actually in my iOS app, I am displaying the text that is received from service. Other Kannada characters are displaying properly but the aforementioned character is not. When I tried to copy and paste it in my project file(Xcode), it will changed to something similar to "ɛ"